# update your xcode error for installing gnuplot on mac

Tags: xcode, gnuplot, homebrew

trying to install gnuplot using this command on terminal

```
Mac:~ Amar$ brew install gnuplot --with-xll
Error: Your Xcode (7.3.1) is too outdated.
Please update to Xcode 8.2 (or delete it).
Xcode can be updated from the App Store
```

but, when in checked if xcode needs to be updated , i get following

```
Mac:~ Amar$ softwareupdate --install xcode
Software Update Tool
Copyright 2002-2015 Apple Inc.

xcode: No such update
No updates are available.
```

Please let me know how to get this problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xcode` is not a valid argument for `softwareupdate`. You need to first use `softwareupdate --list` to get the list of available updates; then use `softwareupdate --install` followed by the update name.

Comment: thanks for the reply .. i did   `softwareupdate --list`  first , however this issue was resolved by by _uninstalling the Xcode_ and installing it again from Apple's developer account.

Answer (score 1):

This error was solved by uninstalling the Xcode and installing it again from Apple's developer account.